# Load image only in desktop version

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

On a website I would like to load my background image only when the user views the page on a laptop or desktop. In the mobile version I do not want the image to show and in addition (!) I do not want it to load.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below to get the bg image usage to be dependent on the screen size. You can set another block of the example below for another screen size

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { /* Adjust as needed */
    body { /* The element or whatever */
        background-image: none;
    }
    }
```

Comment: No need for `!important`.. just makes it harder for the OP to override this at a later point if they need to

Answer (score 1):

use the css:

```
//default css
    body{
        background-image:url(images/image_de_fond.png);
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    // for screen under 640px width the following css will be applied
        body{
            background-image:none;
        }
    }
```